# What is the equivalence of use_javascript of Symfony in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, codeigniter, symfony1

In Symfony, we can use `use_javascript('myscript')` in the view to add a javascript file into the array.

And in the template.php file, we can then use `include_javascripts()` to echo those `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>` in the array:

Is there something similar in Codeigniter?

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: some template libraries have this kind of thing built in if i recall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing in CodeIgniter.. but you could write your own easily.. it's just a library that holds an array of paths to javascript files and renders it on your view.

This [guy did something similar](http://www.codeofficer.com/blog/entry/codeigniter_javascript_library/)... though he uses smarty for his view but you could easily adapt and write an additional render in view method to the library.